# How to troubleshoot IE9 slow response?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, web, diagnostics

I’m dealing with client’s problem that is evident in extremely slow response time only on IE browser (what’s new). Chrome and FF browser works fine.
This slow response is intermittent and is temporarily solved by cleaning cache (client reported that including ssl 2 in internet options -> advanced helps as well).

[image]
Where to start ?!

Answer (score 0):

I find that IE9, in particular, often opens lots of instances. And, if you look in Task Manager, you frequently see one of them hogging memory. I got used to closing IE9 regularly and starting again. 10 and 11 are better in this regard.